# How could I use R to pull a few select lines out of a large text file?

Tags: r

I am fairly new to stack overflow but did not find this in the search engine. Please let me know if this question should not be asked here.

I have a very large text file. It has 16 entries and each entry looks like this:

```
AI_File 10
Version 
Date    20200708 08:18:41
Prompt1 LOC    
Resp1   H****
Prompt2 QUAD   
Resp2   1012   
TransComp   c-p-s
Model   Horizontal
### Computed Results
LAI 4.36
SEL 0.47
ACF 0.879
DIFN    0.031
MTA 40.
SEM 1.
SMP 5
### Ring Summary
MASK    1   1   1   1   1
ANGLES  7.000   23.00   38.00   53.00   68.00
AVGTRANS    0.038   0.044   0.055   0.054   0.030
ACFS    0.916   0.959   0.856   0.844   0.872
CNTCT#  3.539   2.992   2.666   2.076   1.499
STDDEV  0.826   0.523   0.816   0.730   0.354
DISTS   1.008   1.087   1.270   1.662   2.670
GAPS    0.028   0.039   0.034   0.032   0.018
### Contributing Sensors
### Observations
A   1   20200708 08:19:12   x   31.42   38.30   40.61   48.69   60.28
L   2   20200708 08:19:12   1   5.0e-006
B   3   20200708 08:19:21   x   2.279   2.103   1.408   5.027   1.084
B   4   20200708 08:19:31   x   1.054   0.528   0.344   0.400   0.379
B   5   20200708 08:19:39   x   0.446   1.255   2.948   3.828   1.202
B   6   20200708 08:19:47   x   1.937   2.613   5.909   3.665   5.964
B   7   20200708 08:19:55   x   0.265   1.957   0.580   0.311   0.551
```

Almost all of this is junk information, and I am looking to run some code for the whole file that will only give me the lines for "Resp2" and "LAI" for all 16 of the entries. Is a task like this doable in R? If so, how would I do it?

Thanks very much for any help and please let me know if there's any more information I can give to clear anything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've saved your file as a text file and read in the lines. Then you can use regex to extract the desired rows. However, I feel that my approach is rather clumsy, I bet there are more elegant ways (maybe also with (unix) command line tools).

```
data <- readLines("testfile.txt")

library(stringr)
resp2 <- as.numeric(str_trim(str_extract(data, "(?m)(?<=^Resp2).*$")))
lai <- as.numeric(str_trim(str_extract(data, "(?m)(?<=^LAI).*$")))

data_extract <- data.frame(
  resp2 = resp2[!is.na(resp2)],
  lai = lai[!is.na(lai)]
)

data_extract 

  resp2  lai
1  1012 4.36
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I run the "data_eaxtract<-" portion of this code for the full text file (all 16 entries), I get the following error message: ```Error in data.frame(resp2 = resp2[!is.na(resp2)], lai = lai[!is.na(lai)]) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 18, 19```. Do you know what the issue might be?

Comment: this means that you only have 18 entries for resp2 but 19 for lai

Comment: because at data.frame expects the same length of all columns, it throws an error

Comment: Thanks! That took care of the issue. This code works great, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad I could help. If the answer was useful, please consider accepting it

Answer (score 0):

A solution based in the tidyverse can look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(vroom)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

vroom_lines('data') %>%
  enframe() %>%
  filter(str_detect(value, 'Resp2|LAI')) %>%
  transmute(value = str_squish(value)) %>%
  separate(value, into = c('name', 'value'), sep = ' ')

#   name  value
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 Resp2 1012 
# 2 LAI   4.36
```